# Custom class attributes based on parameters using template in C++

Tags: c++

Please tell me how to better implement the task that is written in a non-working code below:

```
enum PointFlags {
        CONSTANT_WIDTH       = 0x01,
        CONSTANT_COLOR       = 0x02,
        CONSTANT_WIDTH_COLOR = 0x03
    };

template <typename point_type = PointFlags>
class Point
{
protected:
        #if (point_type & CONSTANT_WIDTH)
                double width;
        #endif
        #if (point_type & CONSTANT_COLOR)
                double color;
        #endif
public:
        #if (point_type & CONSTANT_WIDTH)
        void setWidth(double w)
        {
             this->width = w;
        }
        #endif
        #if (point_type & CONSTANT_COLOR)
        void setColor(double c)
        {
             this->color = c;
        }
        #endif
}

int main()
{
        int p = CONSTANT_WIDTH | CONSTANT_COLOR;
        Point<PointFlags> a(PointFlags(p));
        a.setWidth(10);
}
```

I need that the attributes (in this case width and color) are been set or not depending on the parameter that is passed to the class template.

I want to reduce the amount of memory used, excluding some attributes depending on which flags are specified.

point_type can be some limited list of number combinations.

Thank you for your help!

**Update:**

**Thank you @HolyBlackCat for your help. I got it worked out. Here is my code for reference if anyone else is working on this:**

```
enum PointFlags {
        CONSTANT_WIDTH       = 0x01,
        CONSTANT_COLOR       = 0x02,
        CONSTANT_OPACITY     = 0x04
    };
struct Empty { };

template <PointFlags T>
class Point
{
protected:
        [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<(T & CONSTANT_WIDTH), int, Empty> width;
        [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<(T & CONSTANT_COLOR), int, Empty> color;
        int point_type;
public:
        Point(PointFlags b = CONSTANT_WIDTH) { 
             point_type = int(T); 
        }

        void setWidth(int w) requires(bool(T & CONSTANT_WIDTH))
        {
             this->width = w;
        }
        void setColor(int c) requires(bool(T & CONSTANT_COLOR))
        {
             this->color = c;
        }
}

int main()
{
        const PointFlags p = PointFlags(CONSTANT_COLOR | CONSTANT_OPACITY);
        Point<p> a;
        a.setColor(10);
}
```

Comment: *"a non-working code below:"* -- OK, we know one of the millions of ways to do the task incorrectly. What is the correct task? Your question would be better by an order of magnitude if you took the time to write out (in words, not code) what you want instead of asking us to guess.

Comment: I think I clearly described my question under the code. Please specify if you have questions. Thanks!

Comment: If the classes are this fundamentally different, why are they even in the same template?

Comment: If you have only 2 or 3 fields and only  a few functions per field, template specialization might works.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, Classes are different only in the example. In production code, they will have a lot in common besides a set of attributes. In fact, I need to have 3 attributes in different combinations. A total of 9 classes will be in the work program. But I need to have an easy way to create them using flags. It will also be a large array, so memory savings are required.

Comment: @Phil1970, Unfortunately I'm not a very good C++ expert. I figured out how to set up a class template and methods template, but I still can't understand how to setup class attributes using templates. Is this possible at all?

Comment: @Conus *"I think I clearly described my question under the code."* -- sorry, but your thinking is incorrect. Under the code you said that something depends on the template parameter, but not *how* it depends. (Also: see [ask] -- the suggestion that you formulate your question before posting any code is a good one.)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Put optional stuff into a base class.

Use one base for width, and one for color.

```
template <bool Enable>
struct PointWidth
{
    double width;

    void setWidth(double w)
    {
        width = w;
    }
};

template <>
struct PointWidth<false> {};
```

Then inherit from `PointWidth<bool(point_type & CONSTANT_WIDTH)>`.

A variant of this trick is to make the base non-template, and inherit from `std::conditional_t<...>` switching between it and an empty structure. If you do this, make sure to use different empty structures for different bases, since [empty-base-optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) will refuse to merge structures of the same type, wasting memory.

Remember that inside of a template, stuff inherited from bases dependent on template parameters can't be accessed directly. You have to use `this` for variables and functions, and `typename SelfType::...` for types (there are other options as well, e.g. `Base::...`). Outside of the template, those restrictions don't apply.

---

**Option 2**: Disable functions and variables individually.

Optional member *functions* are easy - you can disable them with `requires`:

```
void foo() requires(bool(point_type & CONSTANT_WIDTH))
```

This doesn't work for optional member variables though.

You can disable variables using `std::conditional_t<...>` as the type, to switch between the real type and an empty structure.

You should also use `[[no_unique_address]]` to prevent the empty structure from wasting memory. Make sure different fields use different empty structure types, otherwise they won't be able to occupy the same space, just like empty bases.

Comment: I tried to implement option 2, I managed to run the following code:

std::conditional_t<true, int, Empty> width;

but using:
std::conditional_t<bool(point_type & CONSTANT_WIDTH), int, Empty> width;

I get error: C2993 'bool (point_type &)': illegal type for non-type template parameter '_Test'

Can you tell me how to fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: @Conus You need to define `CONSTANT_WIDTH` to 0 when you don't want to use it.

Comment: @Conus Replace `typename point_type` with `PointFlags point_type`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Yes, it works now! I have updated my question with working code. Thank you!